# Arduino library: DFRobotDFPlayerMini

Tags: arduino

I have a problem with the Arduino code. DFRobotDFPlayerMini library. when you press the button, the music plays, and when you press it again, it pauses. I have music playing 0.5 second then repeats. thank you in advance.

```
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
#define BTN_PIN 3
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "DFRobotDFPlayerMini.h"

boolean butt_flag = 0;
boolean butt;
boolean pl;
SoftwareSerial mySoftwareSerial(10, 11); // RX, TX
DFRobotDFPlayerMini myDFPlayer;

void setup()
{
    butt = !digitalRead(3);
    mySoftwareSerial.begin(9600);
    Serial.begin(115200);
    if (!myDFPlayer.begin(mySoftwareSerial)) {
        Serial.println(F("Unable to begin:"));
        Serial.println(F("1.Please recheck the connection!"));
        Serial.println(F("2.Please insert the SD card!"));
        while(true){
            delay(0);
        }
    }
    Serial.println(F("DFPlayer Mini online."));
    pl = 0;
    myDFPlayer.volume(30); 
    myDFPlayer.play(1);
}

void loop()
{
    butt = !digitalRead(3);
    if (butt == 1 && butt_flag == 0) {
        butt_flag = 1;
        pl = !pl;
    }
    if (pl = 1)
        myDFPlayer.play();
    else
        myDFPlayer.pause();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you meet is not related to the library, but you did not debounce your button. For detail about debouncing, you can refer to [this Arduino tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/debounce). The simplest strategy is called "wait and see", the outline looks like this:

```
void loop()
{
  if (!digitalRead(3)) {
    // the button seems to be pressed, but wait...
    delay(200);
    if (!digitalRead(3)) { // check it again
      // the button IS pressed, and change player state
      pl = !pl;
      if (pl = 1)
        myDFPlayer.play();
      else
        myDFPlayer.pause();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It may not be your only problem but in loop 
`if (pl = 1)` should probably be `if (pl == 1)`